# Calculating n-roots of unity in Julia

Tags: julia, algebra

I would like to have an algorithm in Julia depending on $n$, such that it generates the n-roots of unity.

(1,w^{1}, w^{2}, ..., w^{n-1}. Such that for every 1\leq i\leq n, we have that (w^{i})^{n}-1=0 )

Thank you so much for your collaboration,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
julia> roots(n) = map(cispi, range(0, 2, length=n+1)[1:end-1])
roots (generic function with 1 method)

julia> roots(8)
8-element Vector{ComplexF64}:
                 1.0 + 0.0im
  0.7071067811865476 + 0.7071067811865476im
                 0.0 + 1.0im
 -0.7071067811865476 + 0.7071067811865476im
                -1.0 + 0.0im
 -0.7071067811865476 - 0.7071067811865476im
                 0.0 - 1.0im
  0.7071067811865476 - 0.7071067811865476im
```

You could write `roots_exp(n) = exp.(im .* range(0, 2pi, length=n+1)[1:end-1])`, but for a pure imaginary argument, `cis` is slightly more efficient than `exp`. And `cispi` is slightly more accurate, or at least, more likely to give you nice round numbers when you expect them, as shown above.